# How to increment a 'score' during fast enumeration

Tags: cocoa, increment, fast-enumeration

I have the following code which I would like to use to check user answers and output a score (out of 5).  I use a plist with the answers in and check the textField.text against it.  What I'm struggling with is: how to get an output score as a total using this method?

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswers:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"7A Cells Microscopes 3" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path2];

NSString *tester = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", textField.tag];

//   NSDictionary *secondDict = [dictionary valueForKey:tester];

//  NSString *answer = [secondDict valueForKey:@"Answer"];

// if ([textField.text isEqualToString:[[dictionary valueForKey:tester] valueForKey:@"Answer"]]) {
//      NSLog(@"YAY");
//  }

NSArray *allTextFields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eyepiece, objectiveLens, focussingKnobs, stage, mirror, nil];


for (textField in allTextFields) {
                int x = 0;

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:[[dictionary valueForKey:tester] valueForKey:@"Answer"]]) {
        x++;
        NSLog(@"%i", x);
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Many thanks.

Comment: Try declaring x above your for loop. Then it will be in scope after the for loop is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code is good, just move **int x = 0;** outside the for loop. The way you have it coded x is reset to 0 on every loop... so it never counts.

Comment: Sorted, glad for a simple solution! Thank you!